# Django: CreateView fail_url

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I've the following code and I want `form_invalid` method to return the same page as `success_url`.
I've been considering sub-classing `CreateView` but I want to know public opinion.
How to realize the thing described above?

```
class ProgramNew(CreateView):
    form_class = ProgramForm
    template_name = 'programs/program_list.html'
    success_url = '/manage/programs'

    ....
    ....
    ....

    def form_invalid(self, form):    
        # How to return to self.success_url?
        return super(ProgramNew, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def form_invalid(self, form):    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

But I don't know what's the use of this form.

Comment: @sultan I think it's a problem or a REST framework you are using.

Comment: I've fixed this, but for now I've the following error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: for some reason `self.get_success_url()` method returns `None`

Comment: if set the redirect url manually it works, but how pass back invalid form?

Comment: @sultan What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to show form with errors at `success_url`? It isn't a good name for url to show errors at. :-)

Comment: I've a page with the list of items, but the form contains only 2 fields so I want to keep the form in the same page and display error messages if the form is invalid

Comment: @sultan That's exactly what default `form_invalid` does.

Comment: but the form's action actually points to `/manage/programs/new`, I've tried mixin ListView with CreateView and came up with nothing

Comment: @sultan Then view at `/manage/programs/new` should be your `CreateView`

Comment: thank you, I'll still keep the form pointing to `CreateView` and showing `/manage/programs/new` error page if any validation error occurs.)